# Using an Azure VM for Software Development and Testing(and not hosting)

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine

I am starting a new job where I have to buy my own device. This is an year long contract so just need the system for an year.
Now, I was thinking of using an Azure Windows VM for the purpose. I will be doing the below activities.

1. Automation Test code using Java primarily with Eclipse as the IDE
2. Using Chrome and FireFox for browsing around 1-2 GB Data/day
   Does someone has experience using an Azure VM for the Development purpose?

Please note that I am intending to use this VM as my workplace laptop replacement and not for hosting my App/Service on the VM

What all costs should I consider related to the VM? I am currently considering a B4ms 4cores 16GB system with 32 GB temp space. The Azure pricing calculator shows around 45 USD as a month's cost.

Does browsing the Internet on the Azure VM costs you something?

I will be using this machine for 8-9 hours a day for 22 days a month.

Let me know if I am missing something in my calculations or if you need more pointers to answer the questions.

**PS:** I did google the questions but the answers weren't really clear and were mostly Azure advertisements. And also I have a pretty good Internet connection so latency isn't an issue for me.

Comment: Can you provide a summary/screenshot of what you picked in the Azure Calculator?

Comment: @KedMardemootoo [![Azure-Cost.png](https://i.postimg.cc/CxdShfMB/Azure-Cost.png)](https://postimg.cc/WdRQSzkT)

Comment: The answer depends on what resources you require as a developer. For example, I need multiple large monitors to be productive. Cloud VMs work great but are very resource-limited when used as primary development systems at the $50 price point. I would buy a $500 desktop instead. Most professional developers have multiple systems each with multiple monitors. I have three systems that I use constantly at the same time. If one of my systems fails, which does happen, I can quickly continue on another system. Make sure GitHub and traditional backups are part of your daily tasks.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHanley. I would be using just a single screen. And backups will always be in place.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question, there's no problem using a VM for development. We had the same approach initially and then moved on to Azure Virtual Desktop to be more scalable.

My assumption here is that we're being mindful about the cost. Here are things I would consider:

1. Yes there is a cost for EGRESS traffic for Azure  VMs. See [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/) to get a better idea about the cost. I'd say that for your use case it seems that will be roughly an additional USD 4-5 per month. In the calculator I picked `Internet Egress` as the `Data Transfer Type` to `Public Internet`.
2. [Public IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/) (if you're going to RDP to your machine). You could go for a Dynamic IP address (instead of a Static IP) and configure a DNS Label. You would be able to access the VM using the DNS Label instead of the IP address when the IP address changes - every time you stopped(Deallocated) your VM you run the risk getting a different IP address. That's an additional USD 1.
3. If you ever wondered why B-Series are so cheap - You should note that B-series VMs are [Burstable VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-b-series-burstable). Burstable VMs have a base CPU performance and credits you need to accumulate if you want to fully utilize the compute resources that too for a certain number of minutes. Check the article for more info. The advantage is once you've accumulated enough credit you can also go beyond the compute maximum, and with a B4ms, go up to 400%. The caveat is the VM needs to be running to be able to accumulate credits. You can give it a try and if it's not up to your expectations, maybe consider a Dv2 series.
4. [Region](https://azureprice.net/regions) - Since you mentioned you have good internet bandwidth - If region doesn't make much difference to you, you could consider East US region. It generally has the lowest cost for Compute. A B4ms in EUS would be about USD36/month (198hrs/month). The total cost for same environment in East US would be about USD 42/month.

For this simple use case, I don't see any other resources that you would be paying for. You should probably get an Azure Trial account to leverage the first month free (if you've not already done that).

Comment: Thanks, that simplifies it. One more consideration is that currently I don't have a Windows subscription and I was getting confused if I have to buy that before I can create a Windows 10 VM or if that is included in the cost already. When I selected a Windows 10 image it asked me to confirm if I have the multi-tenacy subscription, which I don't. Which image or option should I use ? Any suggestions ?